# FormData with Axios Post to Express - empty fields

Tags: reactjs, mongoose

I have a formData object which is filled with different data. In it I also have, among other things, an array with URLs of images. If I display the entire FormData object in the console, all fields are filled. If I send the whole thing to my Express Server with an axios post command, which should use Mongoose to save the whole thing to my MongoDB database, I always get the error that the name field is a mandatory field. I have also specified this in the model. But that means that the name and description in the backend are empty. How come?

```
const uploadMongoDb = async () => {
let uid = currentUser.uid;

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("userId", uid);
formData.append("name", name);
formData.append("description", description);
formData.append("mainImage", uploadedMainImage);
formData.append("productImages", JSON.stringify(uploadedImages));
formData.append("price", price);
console.log(Object.fromEntries(formData));

await axios
  .post(
    "http://localhost:8888/api/products/",
    { formData },
    { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
  )
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
  })
  .finally(() => setLoading(false));
};
```

On the express side:

```
export const newProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
const name = req.body.name;

console.log("NAME: " + name);
const product = new Product({ ...req.body });

const savedProduct = await product.save();

res.status(200).json(savedProduct);

 } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
 }
};
```